# Symfony 2.8 - One to one form type, relation data empty after submission

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.8

I have two forms for two entities which have a one-to-one relationship:

```
class RelationTwoType ...{
      public function buildForm(...){
             $builder
                 // Problem here: these are empty
                 ->add('some_property_1')
                 ->add('some_property_2')
      }

      public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
      {
           $resolver->setDefaults(array(
              'data_class' => RelationTwo::class,
           ));
      }
}

class RelationType ...{
      public function buildForm(...){
             $builder->add('relationTwo', RelationTwoType::class)
      }

      public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
      {
           $resolver->setDefaults(array(
              'data_class' => Relation::class,
           ));
      }
}
```

However, when I try to submit this nested form, the data is empty? I have no idea why this is the case. The controller logic looks like this:

```
    $relation = new Relation();
    $relationTwo = new RelationTwo();
    $relation->setRelationTwo($relationTwo);

    $form = $this->createForm(RelationType::class, $relation);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
        $relation = $form->getData();
        // this is empty for the nested relation
        dump($form->getData());
        die();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($relation);
        $em->flush();
    }

    // No errors
    dump($form->getErrorsAsString());
    die();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
class RelationsType ...{
  ->add('RelationTwo', RelationTwoType::class)
  ->add('some_property_1')
  ->add('some_property_2')
}
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
       'data_class' => Relation::class,
     ));
 }
```

a simple  `$relation = $form->getData();` should work

good luck